# Error in jquery file and does not give output.

Tags: jquery

I have following jQuery file. I tried my best to find the problem. But, I could not. I am newbie on it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Enter your texts here.

```
    <p id="result"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#count").on("click",function(){
            var strings = $("#textarea").val();
            if(strings=="")
            {
                    $("#result").text("Please put some text to count words");
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"countwords.php",
                    data:{strings:'strings"};
                }).done(function(){
                    $("#result").html(msg);
                });   
            }


        });

        $("#clear").on("click",function(){
            $("#textarea").val("");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: data:{strings:'strings"}; single and double quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this one,

```
    <p>Enter your texts here.</p>
    <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Put Your Text here to Count Your words."></textarea>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="clear"/    >
    <input type="submit" value="Count" id="count"/    >

    <p id="result"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#count").on("click",function(){
            var strings = $("#textarea").val();
            if(strings=="")
            {
                    $("#result").text("Please put some text to count words");
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"countwords.php",
                    data:{strings:strings}
                  //You missed msg arguement
                }).done(function(msg){
                    //alert(msg);
                    $("#result").html(msg);
                });   
            }


        });

        $("#clear").on("click",function(){
            $("#textarea").val("");
        });
    });

</script>
```

1. You missed 'msg' arguement
2. Second you can not put semicolon here, data:{strings:'strings"};

Answer (score 3):

Try to change your `data` value here:

```
data:{strings:'strings"};
```

to:

```
data: {strings:strings} // ; no semi-colon here either
```

and you're also missing the `msg` parameter of your `done` function, should be:

```
.done(function(msg){
 -------------  ^ here ----
     $("#result").html(msg);
});
```